# Kendo UI Grid - Client Template: Escaping # sign

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm working with Kendo UI's grid, along with Twitter Bootstrap.

Twitter Bootstrap has a built in pop-up/modal that can be called with:

```
<a href="#" class="text-yellow" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">Login</a>
```

In my Kendo UI grid, I have a custom column template:

```
   columns.Template(e => { }).ClientTemplate("<span data-toggle='modal' data-target='#login' title='Flag Animals as Dead or Deceased' style='cursor:pointer;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-flag flag-dead text-red'></span>").Width(50);
```

This is where I am having my issue, if you noticed, you need to specify the Id of the modal window with a # sign. ie `data-target='#login'`

Whenever the # sign is in my grid template, the grid breaks. How can I escape this sign?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can escape # using \ character like this `data-target='\#login'`

UPDATE:
From telerik documentation [kendo templates](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview)

> If your template includes a literal # character, which is not part of a binding expression and is not a script code marker, then you must escape that character or it will cause a template compilation error. For example, this can happen if a # is used inside a hyperlink URL or a CSS color value. Literal # in Javascript strings are escaped with \\#, while literal # in external HTML script templates are escaped with \#.

Comment: Remember, that C# Razor will itself need to escape the backslash and so does JavaScript. To get a single backslash to escape the `#` in Kendo client side templates I need to enter ***four*** in my Razor code!