# Kendo UI ClientTemplate includes condition not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am trying to use condition inside ClientTemplate in Kendo UI grid. It does not work for multiple characters. But while using single character like '#' it works.
please suggest a possible soltution. Also can we use ternary operator here?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("marketWatchGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.Clients).ClientTemplate("# if(Clients.indexOf('&#39;')>-1) { # #= Clients # #} else {# #: Clients # #}#")
        })
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a literal hash symbol within a template you need to escape it with one or more \ characters.

[Kendo UI Grid - Client Template: Escaping # sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614529/kendo-ui-grid-client-template-escaping-sign)